# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report - February 2019

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, announcement

## Welcome to the 17th edition of the monthly Ask Different Most Active Contributors Report.

Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback in the comments.

[image: TITLE: REPORT TITLE]

### Report for February 2019

This report includes the following sections:

1. Overall Most Active Contributors Award
2. Monthly Reputation Leader Board
3. Most Active Editors Award
4. Most Active Voters Award
5. Most Active Close Vote Reviewers
6. Most Active First Post Reviewers
7. Most Active Late Answer Reviewers
8. Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers
9. Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers
10. Most Suggested Edits Reviewed Award
11. Highest Voted Questions Award
12. Highest Voted Answers Award
13. Most Viewed Questions Award
14. Ranked 1st Summary List
15. Moderators Activity Summary

---

[image: TITLE: OVERALL MOST ACIVE CONTRIBUTORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Daniil Manokhin           340
2   Allan                     300
3   nohillside                180
4   Nimesh Neema              160
5   bmike                     150
```

**Note:** This is an overall ranking based on all activities. Maximum possible score = 1,150.

---

[image: TITLE: MONTHLY REPUTATION LEADER BOARD]

[image]
A total of 1,653 users earned reputation during the month. You can view the full list [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/118/month/apple/2019-02-01).<sup>1</sup>

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE EDITORS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  EDITS
---------------------------------------
1   bmike                      99
2   IconDaemon                 82
3   Daniil Manokhin            79
4   nohillside                 71
5   Allan                      51
```

A big thank you to all 21 users who edited questions or answers this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE VOTERS AWARD]

```
#   WINNER                  VOTES
---------------------------------------
1   PeterJ                  1,296
2   user97627                 533
3   bmike                     253
4   Monomeeth                 228
5   dwightk                   198
```

A big thank you to all 56 users who voted on questions or answers this month!<sup>3</sup>

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE CLOSE VOTE REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                105
2   Allan                      68
3   Daniil Manokhin            62
4   Nimesh Neema               45
5   Mark                       32
```

A big thank you to all 20 users who reviewed Close Votes this month!

---

[image: TITLE: MOST ACTIVE FIRST POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Daniil Manokhin           334
2   Nimesh Neema              202
3   fsb                       125
4   nohillside                114
5   Allan                     105
```

A big thank you to all 29 users who reviewed First Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LATE ANSWERS REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                     105
2   Daniil Manokhin            48
3   fsb                        41
4   Nimesh Neema               40
5   Mark                       39
```

A big thank you to all 26 users who reviewed Late Answers this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE LOW-QUALITY POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      80
2   Daniil Manokhin            30
3   Nimesh Neema               26
4   Mark                       24
5   Tetsujin, fsb              23
```

A big thank you to all 25 users who reviewed Low-Quality Posts this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE REOPEN POST REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   nohillside                 22
2   Allan                      21
3   Daniil Manokhin            15
4   Tetsujin                   12
5   IconDaemon                  6
```

A big thank you to all 12 users who reviewed Reopen Votes this month!

---

[image: ![TITLE: MOST ACTIVE SUGGESTED EDIT REVIEWERS]

```
#   WINNER                  SCORE
---------------------------------------
1   Allan                      59
2   nohillside                 44
3   Daniil Manokhin            37
4   Nimesh Neema               19
5   Glorfindel                 18
```

A big thank you to all 32 users who reviewed Suggested Edits this month!

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [How can I prove to an airline that the iPad mini they found is the one I left on the plane, without giving them the passcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/350701/168832)

   - Posted by: JDelage
   - Votes: **80**
2. [Strange case of truly invisible file (?) and undeletable directory on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/352599/168832)

   - Posted by: Kusalananda
   - Votes: **19**
3. [Is this an email from Apple or fraud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351542/168832)

   - Posted by: geri wilson
   - Votes: **19**
4. [What makes a MacBook much thicker or thinner?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351223/168832)

   - Posted by: mwafi
   - Votes: **18**
5. [skype wants to export “Apple ID Authentication” from the keychain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351997/168832)

   - Posted by: Aleksandar Ivanisevic
   - Votes: **17**

---

[image: TITLE: HIGHEST VOTED ANSWER AWARD]

1. [How can I prove to an airline that the iPad mini they found is the one I left on the plane, without giving them the passcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350704/168832)

   - Posted by: dwightk
   - Votes: **154**
2. [How can I prove to an airline that the iPad mini they found is the one I left on the plane, without giving them the passcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350730/168832)

   - Posted by: DoubleD
   - Votes: **59**
3. [How can I prove to an airline that the iPad mini they found is the one I left on the plane, without giving them the passcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350738/168832)

   - Posted by: EmLi
   - Votes: **53**
4. [Is this an email from Apple or fraud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351544/168832)

   - Posted by: Christopher
   - Votes: **50**
5. [What makes a MacBook much thicker or thinner?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351224/168832)

   - Posted by: Tetsujin
   - Votes: **43**

---

[image: TITLE: MOST VIEWED QUESTION AWARD]

1. [How can I prove to an airline that the iPad mini they found is the one I left on the plane, without giving them the passcode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/350701/168832)

   - Posted by: JDelage
   - Views: **22,975**
2. [Is this an email from Apple or fraud?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351542/168832)

   - Posted by: geri wilson
   - Views: **8,656**
3. [What makes a MacBook much thicker or thinner?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351223/168832)

   - Posted by: mwafi
   - Views: **4,575**
4. [skype wants to export “Apple ID Authentication” from the keychain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351997/168832)

   - Posted by: Aleksandar Ivanisevic
   - Views: **3,087**
5. [Apparently I’m calling random numbers but there's nothing in the call log](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/351877/168832)

   - Posted by: chris
   - Views: **2,546**

---

[image: TITLE: RANKED 1st SUMMARY LIST]

**1.    Overall Most Active Contributors Award**

- [Daniil Manokhin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin)

**2.    Monthly Reputation Leader Board**

- [Tetsujin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/85275/tetsujin)

**3.    Most Active Editors Award**

- [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

**4.    Most Active Voters Award**

- [PeterJ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/83841/peterj)

**5.    Most Active Close Vote Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**6.    Most Active First Post Reviewers Award**

- [Daniil Manokhin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/310476/daniil-manokhin)

**7.    Most Active Late Answer Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**8.    Most Active Low-Quality Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**9.    Most Active Reopen Post Reviewers Award**

- [Allan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/119271/allan)

**10.   Most Active Suggested Edit Reviewers Award**

- [nohillside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/nohillside)

**11.   Highest Voted Questions Award**

- [JDelage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1710/jdelage)

**12.   Highest Voted Answers Award**

- [dwightk](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/70930/dwightk)

**13.   Most Viewed Questions Award**

- [JDelage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1710/jdelage)

---

[image: TITLE: MODERATORS ACTIVITY SUMMARY]

In February our [Moderators](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) actioned **374 flags** with an average handling time of **17 minutes**. In summary, we also:

- deleted 243 comments
- deleted 203 posts
- closed 213 posts
- edited 275 posts
- created 54 posts
- created 435 comments

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering their time to make this site so great. We appreciate the contributions made by all users, not just those listed in this report!

Keep up the great work! :)

---

<sup>**1.** Due to the possibility of profile changes over time, this link may not reflect the screenshot above.</sup>

<sup>**2.** Only users who have voted over 10 times in the period are counted in this metric.</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Monomeeth for your time and efforts.